# Checking if a string contains a specific word - PHP

Tags: php, strpos, contain

I need to only output true if the sentence contain a specific word.

I know I can use the code below to check if a string contains a word and it will output true.

```
$a = 'How are you?';    

if (strpos($a,'are') !== false) {
echo 'true';
}
else{
echo 'false';
```

But how would I get it to output false if $a  was "Why do you care?"

Comment: And what is the problem with this code?

Comment: It will return 'true' for 'Why do you care?' is the problem. are is in 'care' but the word 'are' is not in the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regex with `\b` anchors for word boundaries:

```
if(preg_match('/\bare\b/i', $sentence)) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

the `i` modifier is for case-insensitivity.